# Как получить значение свойства контрола из другого потока?

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть textbox на форме. С другого потока я хочу считать значение этого контрола. Как вариант, на событие TextChanged() можно повесить обновление свойства, которое хранит значение текстбокса. И брать значение из этого свойства. Не знаю на сколько хороша идея. Пожалуйста, прокомментируйте этот вариант и если можете - предложите свой.

Comment: Control.Invoke со своей лямбдой?

Comment: VladD, да именно так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант

```
var text = (string) tb.Invoke(new Func<string>(() => tb.Text));
```